# How do I make myself an admin and delete old members/staff?

Tags: trello, account-management, user-accounts

My seven-strong team and I are using Trello through Trello.com. Unfortunately, several staff members have left in the past 12 months, including the one who set up the account, and none of us seem to have admin status nor know how to log in as one who does.

How can I set one of us up as the new admin so we can go in and delete inactive members?

Answer (score 3):

Contact support@trello.com with the relevant board/organization and we can transfer ownership to someone else -- there's no way to do this through the site itself (for security reasons).